# How to create /dev/null?

Tags: linux, devices

I deleted my /dev/null. How can I restore it?

Comment: I once found that /dev/null was replaced with a normal file which only root could write to. I thought for a moment that I would have to reinstall everything but as mentioned below, the recovery is trival if you know the trick.

Comment: I managed to remove /dev/null by getting my pipe wrong flipping $ and & around when running an rm command in a script. Ouch!

Comment: @flickerfly You develop scripts as root?

Comment: If the permissions are required, you have to test it eventually. Didn't say it was in production.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

```
mknod /dev/null c 1 3
chmod 666 /dev/null
```

Use these command to create `/dev/null` or use `null(4)` manpage for further help.

Comment: For completeness, I'd note that this applies to all linux-based systems; other systems may have different numbers.

Comment: Also this only sets up the device file itself, it will not restore its permissions. You'll have to `chmod go+w` it manually.

Comment: The number of the beast!

Comment: `mknod -m 0666 /dev/null c 1 3` - same thing but shorter

Comment: `mknod -m 0666 /dev/null c 1 3` worked perfectly to restore /dev/null on CentOS 7, just to let other know.

Comment: I managed to totally bork my `/dev/null`, and these commands didn't help. A reboot reset everything for me.

Answer (score 34):

Under many traditional unices, you can recreate devices with their default permissions with the [`MAKEDEV` script](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/MAKEDEV.8.html). This script is traditionally in `/dev` but is in `/sbin` on Ubuntu. Pass it an argument that indicates what devices you want to create; on Ubuntu that's `std` (you can write `MAKEDEV null` as well, that creates `null` as well as a number of other devices).

Under modern Linux systems running [udev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev), you can tell udev to recreate all or some devices based on available drivers and connected hardware, through [`udevadm trigger`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/udevadm.8.html):

```
udevadm trigger --sysname-match=null
```

Comment: Is this answer still current? I'm on CentOS 7 and I've just overwritten my /dev/null by mistake, the `udevadm trigger --sysname-match=null` trick didn't work for me, while `mknod -m 0666 /dev/null c 1 3` worked perfectly.

Comment: @Bozzy I know it worked with the pre-systemd udev. I haven't tried recently, but as far as I know this should still work. If you add `--verbose`, does it list `/sys/devices/virtual/mem/null
`?

Comment: Yes, it lists that. I've tried to overwrite again /dev/null on my dev machine, but strangely enough I'm unable to do it here, so I can't do a more in-depth analysis now...

Answer (score 0):

When I accidentally deleted /dev/null, a simple `sudo reboot`seemed to restore it.
It did cause my desktop icons to go crazy, but no damage seemed to be done
If that doesn't the other answers probably will be more help