# How are "/dev" Linux files created?

Tags: linux, files, devices

There are special files in Linux that are not really files.

The most notable and clear examples of these are in the `dev` folder, "files" like:

- `/dev/null` - Ignores anything you write to the file
- `/dev/random` - Outputs random data instead of the contents of a file
- `/dev/tcp` - Sends any data you write to this file over the network

First of all, what is the name of these types of "files" that are really some sort of script or binary in disguise?

Second, how are they created? Are these files built into the system at a kernel level, or is there a way to create a "magic file" yourself (how about a `/dev/rickroll`)?

Comment: I had no clue how to tag this question, especially since I don't know the name of what I'm looking for. Feel free to edit in any relevant tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create /dev/null?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27279/how-to-create-dev-null)

Comment: @cuonglm That's how to restore the special file after it has been deleted. Thanks, it may provide some helpful insight, but I wouldn't call it a duplicate.

Comment: BTW, this is a fundamental part of the design of unix and unix-like operating systems: (almost) everything is a file, or can be made to look like a file.

Comment: Also See: mknod(2)  `man 2 mknod`

Comment: These are "device nodes".  However the ones you mentioned - unlike those associated with disks, keyboard, mice, audio-cards, and other devices - are so-called "pseudo-devices", as they're not "real" devices and only exists in the kernel.  It's possible to create new ones, by writing a suitable device-driver and add it to the kernel (eg. a pseudo-device for monitoring some activity on the computer).  Before the /dev-directory existed on disk - these days it's a virtual file-system (of type devfs) created by the kernel.

Comment: The suggested duplicate indicates how you create these _in the filesystem_. But it doesn't explain what _backs_ them or how they work. I suggest editing the question tittle to ask about that instead.

Comment: All files, even "real" files, are software artifacts. The software behind every device, file, socket, special file, or something yet to be invented provides a table of functions to handle `open()`, `read()`, `close()`, etc. After that, it's up to the software

Comment: true devfs is not commonly used today, the common method (udev) has the device files on-disk but managed by a monitor daemon that will remove and create them at the behest of the kernel and device drivers. Running a linux system with the device files on-disk and manually maintained is still perfectly possible, but awkward unless it is eg a server whose hardware (including externally attached devices) is not expected to change, BTW, "MAKEDEV generic" will populate a /dev directory reasonably if you ever have to .

Answer (score 116):

`/dev/zero` is an example of a "special file" — particularly, a "device node". Normally these get created by the distro installation process, but you can *totally* create them yourself if you want to.

If you ask `ls` about `/dev/zero`:

```
# ls -l /dev/zero
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 5  Nov 5 09:34 /dev/zero
```

The "c" at the start tells you that this is a "character device"; the other type is "block device" (printed by `ls` as "b"). Very roughly, random-access devices like harddisks tend to be block devices, while sequential things like tape drives or your sound card tend to be character devices.

The "1, 5" part is the "major device number" and the "minor device number".

With this information, we can use the `mknod` command to make our very own device node:

```
# mknod foobar c 1 5
```

This creates a new file named `foobar`, in the current folder, which does *exactly* the same thing as `/dev/zero`. (You can of course set different permissions on it if you want.) All this "file" really contains is the three items above — device type, major number, minor number. You can use `ls` to look up the codes for other devices and recreate those too. When you get bored, just use `rm` to remove the device nodes you just created.

Basically the major number tells the Linux kernel which device driver to talk to, and the minor number tells the device driver which device you're talking about. (E.g., you probably have one SATA controller, but maybe multiple harddisks plugged into it.)

If you want to *invent* new devices that do something new... well, you'll need to edit the source code for the Linux kernel and compile your own custom kernel. So let's not do that! :-) But you can add device files that duplicate the ones you've already got just fine. An automated system like udev is basically just watching for device events and calling `mknod` / `rm` for you automatically. Nothing more magic than that.

There are still *other* kinds of special files:

- Linux considers a directory to be a special kind of file. (Usually you can't directly open a directory, but if you could, you'd find it's a normal file that contains data in a special format, and tells the kernel where to find all the files in that directory.)
- A symlink is a special file. (But a hard link isn't.) You can create symlinks using the `ln -s` command. (Look up the manpage for it.)
- There's also a thing called a "named pipe" or "FIFO" (first-in, first-out queue). You can create one with `mkfifo`. A FIFO is a magical file that can be opened by *two* programs at once — one reading, one writing. When this happens, it works like a normal shell pipe. But you can start each program separately...

A file that isn't "special" in any way is called a "regular file". You will occasionally see mention of this in Unix documentation. That's what it means; a file that isn't a device node or a symlink or whatever. Just a normal, every day file with no magical properties.

Comment: There's also one more type of special file, a Unix domain socket bound to the filesystem.

Comment: If you want to play with `mknod`, run `cat /proc/devices` to see the major numbers for all drivers. Which brings us to yet another kind of special file the `/proc` file system ([this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/241180/90379) talks about it).

Comment: Other Unices have invented their own special files, e.g. Solaris had [doors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doors_%28computing%29).

Comment: Minor nitpick: you don't have to recompile the kernel to write a new character/block device :) http://www.crashcourse.ca/introduction-linux-kernel-programming/lesson-17-your-first-character-device-driver Otherwise this is a really good answer, +1!

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid is this Linux-specific or POSIX-mandated behaviour?

Comment: Never knew about named pipes, thats pretty cool. Can you have multiple readers on a named pipe?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg, negative. If you want fancy things like fanout queues implemented natively, you might look at what the kdbus people are doing.

Comment: @ArtB It's a mixture of both. For example, FIFOs are in POSIX I think.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid: A step your reply is missing (or at least only stating implicitly) is the fact that those special files are not disguised shell scripts or binaries at all (as the question implied), but rather an interface to access functionality that is present in the OS kernel.

Comment: @ArtB I have never seen a Unix that isn't Linux, so I can't comment authoritatively. However, I'm pretty certain they all have the concept of special files, and I think the major number / minor number stuff is universal. Not very sure what other kinds of special file are common though...

Comment: You can also use `mknod` to create named pipes: `mknod filename p`. I'm not sure if this is POSIX -- it's not an option in the BSD version on OS X.

Answer (score 36):

Most of the `/dev` entries are block device inodes or character device inodes. [Wikipedia has many details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file)about that, which I am not going to repeat.

But `/dev/tcp` which is mentioned in your question is not explained by any of the existing answers. `/dev/tcp` and `/dev/udp` are different from most other `/dev` entries. The block and character devices are implemented by the kernel, but `/dev/tcp` and `/dev/udp` are implemented in user mode.

The bash shell is one program which has an implementation of `/dev/tcp` and `/dev/udp` (copied from `ksh93`). When you try to open a path beneath those with bash redirection operators, it will not perform an ordinary `open` system call. Instead bash will create a TCP socket and connect it to the specified port.

That is implemented in user mode and only in some programs as can be seen in the following example which demonstrates the difference between letting `bash` and `cat` try to open `/dev/tcp/::1/22`

```
$ cat /dev/tcp/::1/22
cat: /dev/tcp/::1/22: No such file or directory
$ cat < /dev/tcp/::1/22
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3
```

A difference with `ksh93` is that `bash` will only do those TCP connections with redirection operators, not in the other places where it may open files like the `source` or `.` builtin.

Comment: Also, GNU awk `gawk` similarly special-cases `/inet{,4,6}/{tcp,udp}/$port/$remote/$rport`, since somewhere around 2010 (I don't recall exactly and can't find release notes).

Comment: IMO, a better way to state the point about `/dev/tcp` is that it's NOT a file.  There is never a **file** called this.  Bash's syntax for opening sockets uses the string `/dev/tcp/address` like a filename, but calling it a "file implemented in user space" just sounds weird.  Interesting that `ksh` hooks those filenames for everything, not just redirects, though.  That's closer to "implementing a file".

Comment: @PeterCordes i believe UWIN  sets these up as actual files. and i think 3dfs does the same. remember, `bash` only copied this behavior, but it originates elsewhere.

Answer (score 21):

In addition of device nodes explained in other answers (created with [mknod(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mknod.2.html) or supplied by some [devfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#DEVFS)), Linux has other "magical" files provided by special [virtual file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_file_system), in particular in `/proc/` (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), read about [procfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs)) and in `/sys/` (read about [sysfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs)).

These pseudo files (which appear -e.g. to [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html)- as ordinary files, not as devices) are a virtual view provided by the kernel; in particular, reading from `/proc/` (e.g. with `cat /proc/$$/maps`, or by [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)-ing `/proc/self/status` in your program) generally does not involve any physical I/O from disk or network, so is quite fast.

To create some additional pseudo-file in `/proc/` you generally should write your own [kernel module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loadable_kernel_module) and load it (see e.g. [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-proc/index.html)).

Comment: AFAIK the information on extending /proc is outdated. While still technically possible, /proc (or rather procfs) should only hold information on running processes. All other pseudo-files including those that contain runtime information or configuration options for the kernel should go into /sys (sysfs). There are still some non process-related pseudo files in /proc (e.g. meminfo, cpuinfo) for compatibility reasons, but new pseudo files should go into sysfs.

Answer (score 13):

They're called device nodes, and are created either manually with `mknod` or automatically by `udev`.  They are typically file-like interfaces to character or block devices with drivers in the kernel - e.g. disks are block devices, ttys and serial ports etc are character devices.

There are other "special" file types too, including named pipes and fifos and sockets.

Answer (score 13):

As other users have already explained in great detail, special files require code to back them up. However, nobody seems to have mentioned that Linux provides several ways to write that code in userspace:

**A.** [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) (Filesystem in USErspace) allows you to write something like `/proc` without risk of crashing the kernel and do it in a language/runtime of your choice, such as [Go](https://github.com/hanwen/go-fuse), [Node.js](https://github.com/mafintosh/fuse-bindings), [Perl](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=938307), [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144707/fuse-bindings-for-php), [Python](http://www.stavros.io/posts/python-fuse-filesystem/),  [Ruby](https://github.com/lwoggardner/rfusefs), [Rust](https://zsiciarz.github.io/24daysofrust/book/day15.html), [etc.](http://sourceforge.net/p/fuse/wiki/LanguageBindings/).

It also has the advantage that FUSE filesystems can be mounted without `sudo` because they run as the user doing the mounting.

Here are some examples of things people have written using FUSE:

- [mp3fs](https://khenriks.github.io/mp3fs/) (View your FLAC files as MP3 files that get created on-the-fly when you copy/click-drag them to your MP3 player)
- [PyTagsFS](https://launchpad.net/pytagsfs) (View your media in a tree of virtual folders built from the metadata tags)
- [fuse-zip](https://bitbucket.org/agalanin/fuse-zip) (Mount Zip files as folders)
- [FuseISO](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fuseiso/) (Mount ISOs without root permissions)
- [iFUSE](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ifuse) (Mount iDevices)
- [FuseDAV](https://github.com/pantheon-systems/fusedav) (Mount WebDAV shares)
- [fuse-exfat](https://github.com/relan/exfat) (Mount exFAT-formatted filesystems)
- [ntfs-3g](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS-3G) (**The** Linux NTFS driver)

**B.** If you want to create a virtual input device like a keyboard, mouse, joystick, etc. (eg. to write a userspace driver for a USB device you're talking to using `libusb`), there's [uinput](http://thiemonge.org/getting-started-with-uinput).

Bindings for it are harder to find, but I know they exist for [Go](https://github.com/galaktor/gostwriter) (Keyboard-only), [Python](http://tjjr.fi/sw/python-uinput/), and [Ruby](https://github.com/christopheraue/ruby-uinput-device) [(2)](https://github.com/christopheraue/ruby-uinput-keyboard).

Examples of real-world uinput use include:

- [G15Daemon](http://sourceforge.net/projects/g15daemon/) (Linux driver for the LCD and gaming keys on Logitech G15 gaming keyboards)
- [ds4drv](https://github.com/chrippa/ds4drv) (Driver for Sony DualShock 4 controllers)
- [xboxdrv](http://pingus.seul.org/~grumbel/xboxdrv/) (Alternative XBox 360 controller driver and Linux equivalent to [x360ce](http://www.x360ce.com/default.aspx) so badly designed games like [Runner2: Future Legend of Rhythm Alien](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runner2:_Future_Legend_of_Rhythm_Alien) can think they're talking to a real XBox controller when they're not)
- The old Wiimote drivers like [cwiid](http://www.abstrakraft.org/cwiid/) that were required before someone finally wrote a kernel Wiimote driver so support would be available by default.

**C.** For generic character devices, there's [CUSE](https://lwn.net/Articles/308445/) (Character devices in USErspace). It's much less popular though.

The only user of the CUSE API that I'm personally aware of is the same program which prompted its creation: [osspd](http://sourceforge.net/projects/osspd/), which implements `/dev/dsp`, `/dev/adsp`, and `/dev/mixer` (the OSS audio API) in userspace so they can be routed through PulseAudio or dmix.

The only CUSE binding I was able to find is [cusepy](https://github.com/piranna/cusepy), which hasn't been updated since 2010.

**D.** You may not need a new special file at all.

For example, you can open up raw communication with any USB device using [libusb](http://www.libusb.org/) (List of bindings on the page) and then communicate with other programs through some other mechanism (TCP/UDP sockets, reading/writing stdin/stdout or regular files on disk, etc.).

Comment: cusepy might not have been updated in a while (in fact, it's never been updated; it only has one commit!), but having just written a character device using cusepy a few weeks ago, I can confirm it still works fine. It was missing a few functions related to implementing `poll`, but since cusepy uses ctypes and the bindings are autogenerated based on C header files, fixing any missing functions is just a matter of adding the desired function name to the list of exported functions in the `setup.py`.

Comment: Another interesting example of FUSE usage is [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html). It allows you to browse remote file system as if it was local using SSH connection underneath.

Comment: @Mr.Deathless Yeah. I actually use that and meant to mention it but I forgot.

Answer (score 6):

The book [Linux Device Drivers](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) (highly recommended) explains this in detail, and even has you create a kernel module that does this as an example, but in a nutshell, each device driver has specific functions that get called when a file is opened, closed, read, written, etc.  The "special" files just do something special inside those functions, instead of accessing the storage hardware on a disk.

For example, the write function for `/dev/null` just does nothing, ignoring the bytes.  The read function for `/dev/random` returns a random number.

Answer (score 2):

**`mount -t devtmpfs`**

In many modern systems, `/dev` is normally filesystem type that can be mounted wherever you want. E.g. on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
mkdir d
sudo mount -t devtmpfs none d
head -c 10 d/random
sudo umount d
```

and now `d/` contains the exact same as `/dev`.

This is enabled by `CONFIG_DEVTMPFS=y`, and allows the kernel itself to create and destroy device files as needed.

**`CONFIG_DEVTMPFS_MOUNT=y`**

This option makes the kernel auto-mount devtmpfs on `/dev` during boot. It is for example enabled on Ubuntu 21.04.

[`drivers/base/Kconfig`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.9/drivers/base/Kconfig#L47) documents:

```
config DEVTMPFS_MOUNT
    bool "Automount devtmpfs at /dev, after the kernel mounted the rootfs"
    depends on DEVTMPFS
    help
      This will instruct the kernel to automatically mount the
      devtmpfs filesystem at /dev, directly after the kernel has
      mounted the root filesystem. The behavior can be overridden
      with the commandline parameter: devtmpfs.mount=0|1.
      This option does not affect initramfs based booting, here
      the devtmpfs filesystem always needs to be mounted manually
      after the rootfs is mounted.
      With this option enabled, it allows to bring up a system in
      rescue mode with init=/bin/sh, even when the /dev directory
      on the rootfs is completely empty.
```

**`file_operations`**

Finally, you should create your own character device kernel module to see exactly what is going on.

Here is a minimal runnable example: [How do character device or character special files work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37829/understanding-character-device-or-character-special-files/371758#371758)

The most important step, is setting up the `file_operations` struct, e.g.:

```
static const struct file_operations fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .read = read,
    .open = open,
};

static int myinit(void)
{
    major = register_chrdev(0, NAME, &fops);
    return 0;
}
```

which contains function pointers that get called for each file-related system call.

It then becomes obvious that you override those file-related system calls to do whatever you want, and so this is how the kernel implements devices like `/dev/zero`.

**Create `/dev` entries at automatically without `mknod`**

The final mystery is how the kernel automatically creates `/dev` entries.

The mechanism can be observed by making a kernel module that does that yourself as shown at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970595/how-to-create-a-device-node-from-the-init-module-code-of-a-linux-kernel-module/45531867#45531867 and comes down to a `device_create` call.

Comment: In OpenBSD there's a script MAKEDEV that simplifies this a little, see https://man.openbsd.org/MAKEDEV.8  Not sure why Linux doesn't have it except it's way more complicated.  Maybe parts could be adapted.  You can say MKNOD tty for example and it handles the details.