# What is the file of a USB in Android?

Tags: android

Considering that Android uses the Linux kernel, and that it reflects the recognized devices in /dev, /media and /run/media, where is the equivalent of fe. /dev/sda for a USB flash?

I know Android isn't GNU, but I'm guessing it's the same thing when it comes to drives.

Comment: You mentioned both device nodes and mountpoints in your question. Figure out what you really want to ask / know. The device node is almost certainly /dev/sdX because that's naming for **s**csi **d**isks in Linux. (Both MSC and UAS drives talk scsi.) Mountpoints are always arbitrary, but in modern Android it's usually, if not always, `/storage/$fs_uuid`. (For FAT family formatted drive, it would be something like `/storage/1A2B-3C4D`.

Comment: Hmm actually I was wrong about device node. It's somewhat arbitrary as well: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241173/how-are-dev-linux-files-created